# How to prevent object copying in arraylIst in java

Tags: java, arraylist, clone

I have an arrayList of object Player. Player has field id, and score. suppose arrayList has `player object with id:1, score:200` now when i add `player with id:1 and score :300`, arraylist have now two object but both with score 200. whereas it should be one with score 100 and one with score.
I tried clone() method as `arrayList.add(player.clone())` but it did not solve my problem.

**code:**

```
Player player= playerService.getPlayerById(id);
player.SetScore(100);
challenge.getPlayerList().add(player.clone());
here challenge is an object which has an attribute playerlist
```

Please suggest.
Thanks.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the (short) code that you are using.

Comment: ...and also fix your question, it's difficult to follow...

Comment: Your piece of code would help

Comment: Please paste your code. Just to see what mistakes you have done.

Comment: First half of the question is clear. But the second half makes the complete thing vague. Edit the question and emphasize on what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without you showing some code, I'm guessing you're adding the same Player object but with different values. If you:

- Add a Player with id: 1 and score: 100
- Change the values of that Player object to score: 200
- Add that object again

You will have 2 Players in your list with the last values of the Player object.

Somewhere you need to do a `new Player()` with new values, not just re-use the same Player object.

Read this article about call-by-reference, call-by-value: http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2000-05/03-qa-0526-pass.html

Comment: Thanks, using a new Player with same id and new score worked :)

Answer (score 4):

Its a common mistake to assume that adding an object to a list/array copies it.

If truth, you add references to a collection, not the object and *it is the reference which is copied*.

You create a new object each time `new` or `clone()` is called only.

```
// Don't do this
Player p = new Player(1, 100);
list.add(p);
list.add(p); // adds a reference to the same object.

// Do this
list.add(new Player(1, 100));
list.add(new Player(2, 200));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you add two instances of `Player` to the list, then the list will have both items, even if the two instances are the same object.

If you see your second instance with wrong values, then you either

- added a wrong object or
- looked at the wrong place/index (in the list)

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
Player player= playerService.getPlayerById(id);
player.SetScore(100);
challenge.getPlayerList().add(player.clone());
```

As you've realised adds two duplicate items to the list. If I'm reading you're question right you really want to do something like:

```
Player player= playerService.getPlayerById(id);
Player clone = (Player)player.clone();
clone.SetScore(100);
challenge.getPlayerList().add(clone);
```

This only sets the score of the *new* player not of both. So now you will have a list with a player with the original score and a player with score 100.